# Replace multiple substrings between delimiters in Java

Tags: java, regex

I have the following strings:

```
String str1 = "could be";
String str2 = "bigger";
```

and want to convert this string:

```
String toConvert = "I ||am|| a ||small|| string.";
```

into this one:

```
"I could be a bigger string."
```

How can I do that in Java?

Comment: What have you tried so far? and what exactly is your logic?

Comment: `toConvert.replace("||am||", "could be")` etc?

Comment: HINT: `String` has a method called `replace`.

Comment: but if I do not know the text between the delimiters?

Comment: Yeah, that's the point, so you need a repetition of a word character between `||` marks. Happy trying.

Comment: I still do not understand the logic and without how can I help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50731350/replace-multiple-substrings-between-delimiters-in-java#comment88470556_50731350):

> but if I do not know the text between the delimiters?

So it sounds like the replacement values are *positional*.

Best way to do this is a regular expression [`appendReplacement`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#appendReplacement-java.lang.StringBuffer-java.lang.String-) loop:

```
public static String replace(String input, String... values) {
    StringBuffer buf = new StringBuffer();
    Matcher m = Pattern.compile("\\|{2}(.*?)\\|{2}").matcher(input);
    for (int i = 0; m.find(); i++)
        m.appendReplacement(buf, (i < values.length ? values[i] : m.group(1)));
    return m.appendTail(buf).toString();
}
```

*Test*

```
String toConvert = "I ||am|| a ||small|| string.";
System.out.println(replace(toConvert, "could be")); // "small" is retained without markers
System.out.println(replace(toConvert, "could be", "bigger"));
System.out.println(replace(toConvert, "could be", "bigger", "better")); // "better" is ignored
```

*Output*

```
I could be a small string.
I could be a bigger string.
I could be a bigger string.
```